# how to find the right vm_area_struct from a mm_strucnt and a buffer

Tags: linux, kernel

so in the mm_strucnt  there is list of  vm_areas ,

```
struct vm_area_struct *mmap_cache;
```

and I want to find the one that contain my buffer for example function that would get sturc_mm and would return the vm_area that contain my buffer

```
get_vmArea(userbuffer,current->mm)
```

do there is any function that can do it for me, so I wouldn't have to look for all the vm_area till I find the one that contains rang that include my address

Answer (score 0):

This function can be used

struct vm_area_struct *find_vma(struct mm_struct *mm, unsigned long addr)